# Light intensity as function of exposure and image brightnes

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, photo

I want to measure the light intensity of microscope images with a BW camera attached to the microscope. My purpose is to compare particular images with each other concerning their brightness. I'm neither interested in measuring absolute light intensity nor in units.

I think, the Function should use exposure and some brightness-related metric (e.g. thresholded histogram-width or pixel-value mean).

My first attempt: 1/exposure * brightness works for smaller exposure ranges.

The exposure is a real [0.001..0.6], the brightens is a natural number [0..255].
Is there a formula for calculating the light intensity received by camera having these two figures?

Many thanks for suggestions!

P.S.:
Currently I estimate the intensity using fuzzy-logic. It works, but the calibration is not flexible.

**EDIT:** 
I've got additional information from the camera manufacturer. The function of light is linear when the pixel values are within the range 50-200

Comment: It's unusual to have a camera with a linear output. Most apply a gamma function at least.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I'll try to verify this.

Answer (score 1):

You say "I'm neither interested in measuring absolute light intensity nor in units.". So I guess you only want to answer questions like: "The light source in this image was shining N-times as bright as in this other image: what is N?".

Of course estimating an answer to such a question from images makes sense only if everything else stays (approximately) the same: microscope, camera, transmission (or reflection) of the imaged sample, etc. Is this the case?

If the content of the images is approximately the same, I'd just start by comparing image-wide statistics: ratio of the median/average/n-th quantile intensities, and see if there is a common shift. Be careful if your image are 8-bit per channel: you will probably have to linearize them by removing whatever gamma compression was applied before computing the stats.

As you notice, however, things get more complicated when the variation in exposure increase, probably because on nonlinear effects (cutoff at the lower end or saturation at the higher end).

Comment: "The light source in this image was shining N-times as bright as in this other image" - exactly! The image contents varies, but I normalize it (use only cell-areas, no background)

Answer (score 1):

The exposure might be in seconds or some unit of time. Then your first attempt should be right:

1/exposure * brightness

A possible problem might be the flash. If it flashes during 10ms and your exposure is <10ms there is no problem, but if your exposure is >10ms, then the result will be similar to 10ms (depending on how much light there is in the room apart from the flash).

I would take several pictures at the same object changing the exposure. Plot the brightness vs exposure and it should be a diagonal line, if not, the shape might give you some clues. If at some point the line flattens, probably the flash has not enough duration.

A flash can have more issues, like bad synchronization with the exposure or non uniform brightness during all the exposure (it might take some fraction of millisecond to achieve the maximum brightness, for example).

It there is no flash, a gamma correction could be the problem as has been suggested. In any case, a plot of brightness vs exposure may help.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your ideas! I don't use flash but a 60Watt LED. It is not blinking while camera makes shots. I've actually made a plot and saw a raising line, as you write. However I couldn't make a reasonable conclusion. I'll update the question with the data soon. P.S.:<10ms Would solve a couple of my problems :-) In fact, my usual exposure times are between 100-600 ms. It is a fluorescence microscopy application with 200x magnification, so the light intensity is very low.

Comment: Maybe you can attach the plot. Maybe it is better to test with a white sheet of paper (a uniform surface) because gamma corrections affect differently if the pixels are dark or bright.

Comment: Sorry, have not managed to attach the plot till now. I'll start another bounty (or re-phrase this question) with more information,  as I have not got satisfying answer yet.